# Show by Induction, but stuck on Induction Step (Don't know how to implement N = K+1)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

> Prove by Induction that 
>   $$
> 1\cdot 2\cdot3  +  2\cdot3\cdot4 + \cdots + n \cdot(n+1)\cdot(n+2) = \frac{n  (n+1)(n+2)  (n+3)}{4}
> $$

For my basis step, I set $$n=0$$
This leaves me with zero on both LHS and RHS, so I proceed.
Induction Hypothesis consists of plugging in $N = K$ assuming the basis step applies for $$ k \leq n $$

After this, I am stuck on the Induction Step. I try to solve for $n = k+1$, but I don't know what to do.

Due to requests asking me to show what I have tried:
$$
(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}{4}
$$
I don't know where to go from here. I don't think it is correct anyways.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: It is now updated @SeanRoberson

Comment: In the last part, do you mean this? $$(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) \color{red}{+} \frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}{4}$$

Comment: If you compare the first term, $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3$, with the "$n^\text{th}$ term, $n \cdot (n+1) \cdot (n+2)$, then you can see that you should start with $n=1$, not $n=0$. This may be a trivial observation, but, proof by induction is an exercise in paying attention to detail.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By assumption of the induction we obtain:
$$1\cdot2\cdot3+\dots+n(n+1)(n+2)+(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)=$$
$$=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{4}+(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)=$$
$$=(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\left(\frac{n}{4}+1\right)=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}{4}.$$
Can you end it now?

Answer (score 0):

Just sum both sides $(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ yo your Induction Hypothesis. So you get:

$(1)(2)(3) + ... + n(n+1)(n+2) + (n+1)(n+2)(n+3) = \frac{(n)(n+1)(n+2)}{4}+(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)=\frac{(n)(n+1)(n+2)+4(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{4}=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}{4}$

Answer (score -1):

@user758853.

Your question is actually similar to this:

Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i \times (i+1) = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}$

To solve this, you multiply both sides by 3, then do the following

$ 1 \times 2 \times 3 = 1 \times 2 \times (3-0) = 1 \times 2 \times 3 - 0$

$ 2 \times 3 \times 3= 2 \times 3 \times (4-1) = 2 \times 3 \times 4 - 1\times 2 \times 3 $

$ 3 \times 4 \times 3= 3 \times 4 \times (5-2) = 3 \times 4 \times 5 -2 \times 3 \times 4 $

...

Do you recognize the pattern now?

By using the same method you do not have to use induction anymore, just **multiply each sides of your equation by 4 instead of 3** and you will find the given equation correct.

**EDITS**

I think mathematical induction also applies, and if you don't know how to do it, just follow these steps:

- Apply your induction hypothesis to the first $n$ factors of the sum
- Add the $(n+1)th$ factor to the LHS, and write what you need to prove on the RHS.
- Try reducing both sides to the same denominator and expand both sides then you should see it apparently true.

**Q.E.D**

Comment: The "similar question" is proving a false equation. The example solution(?) is not clear at all. Overall this answer is hard to follow and seems to have several glaring issues. -1

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I am sorry, it was my careless mistake. I edited it so it would be true and my example solution is clearer, right?